# Why can't Doctor Strange make Thanos fall forever?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

How is Thanos even a threat to Earth or the universe, given there exists sorcerer supreme Doctor Strange on Earth which hosts several Infinity Stones right now?

Why can't Doctor Strange make Thanos fall forever?

Comment: Well, then it would be a very *finite* war. Not good for business you see Widow.

Comment: `on Earth which hosts several Infinity Stones right now` - What does this mean? How is it relevant? I'm also tempted to close this as per our Future Works Policy. We'll likely find out why Doctor Strange can't magic away Thanos in the film.

Comment: Earth currently has at least 2 infinity stones (Vision's forehead and Strange's eye of Agamotto). Two out of six on a single planet? Thats huge in comparison to the size of universe. @Edlothiad I guess Widow meant that.

Comment: 1. That's not several, 2. That's entirely logical given 99.99999999% of everything that happens in the "entire universe" happens on Earth or with relation to Earth. It really doesn't seem _that_ significant that there are 2 infinity stones on Earth, we also know one will be reclaimed by Thanos

Comment: You can't make someone fall forever when you're dead. Doctor Strange is not Sorcerer Supreme. The position remains vacant since the Ancient One died. Also, Thanos is the most powerful being in the universe. I think someone said so in Guardians 1. So, simply, because Thanos already murdered him.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the start of *Avengers: Infinity War* we see Thanos claim the Tesseract from Loki, break it open and get the Space Stone inside which he puts into the Infinity Gauntlet. The Space Stone has the power to let Thanos teleport anywhere in the universe he wants.

Doctor Strange only meets Thanos when he is on Titan and we clearly see Thanos has the Space Stone since he arrives by using it. Even if Strange couldn't work out that Thanos has the Space Stone from this, Banner had already told him.

> **Bruce Banner:** No telling. He has the Power and Space Stones, that already makes him the strongest creature in the whole universe. If he gets his hands, on all six Stones, Tony...
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Therefore, there would be no point in attempting to make Thanos fall forever because he could simply just teleport himself out of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

**Thanos** is one of the most powerful being in the Marvel Universe. (I will not be listing his abilities as it is a huge list). But one of his well-known abilities is his Mystical knowledge. This has been mentioned in several instances including : ***Thanos # 7*** (summary [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Thanos_Vol_1_7)) and  ***Deadpool # 64*** (summary [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Deadpool_Vol_1_64)). For instance, Thanos cursed Deadpool with an immortality curse so that he could never die which even Death cannot undo.

For someone being so well-versed with the Mystical arts, I'd say it would be very difficult for Dr. Strange to simply float him away or make him fall forever.

***PS:*** However, unless we fully get to know Thanos' powers in the MCU, we cannot say *why* Strange can't do what he did to Loki (or as a matter of fact the Time-reversal thingy he did to Dormammu either).

Comment: The scope here is the MCU, Ideally your answer would focus there.

Comment: @Edlothiad Well, in that case, this question can only be answered after *IW* is released. So right now it is more like an opinion-based question.

Comment: And that's why we have the future works policy, and that's why I've applied it :).

Comment: The time reversal strategy was only valid against Dormammu because it exists outside of time and therefore could experience being trapped repeating the same actions again and again. If Thanos does not exist beyond time then he would never grow bored of the trap because for him it would always be the first time there.

Comment: Also he has the space stone to literally teleport out of the hole.

Answer (score -1):

Ultimately, Strange’s time magic is just a way of controlling the power of the time stone. However, it’s power is greater than any magic he can do without it. His portals are good, but are useless against the space stone. Thanos could escape instantly.